# Sonar: 0 files indexed in one project, properly scanned in another

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have 2 [Jenkins shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) which contain groovy files to be scanned. Both projects are using the same sonarqube call using maven but in one project the groovy files are scanned, whereas in the other they are not

**Sonarqube call**

```
...
    String scanCmd = "mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar " +
            "-f pom.xml " +
            "-Dsonar.branch=%GIT_BRANCH% " +
            "-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/** " +
            "-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/** " +
            "-Dsonar.skipDesign=true "

    bat scanCmd
...
```

We are using version 5.6.6, if that matters

**Sonar scanner config**

The sonar configuration is in the parent pom which contains the sonar properties

```
....
   <properties>
        <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.sources>src,vars</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.inclusions>**/**</sonar.inclusions>
    </properties>
....
```

Both projects (pom.xml) use the this parent pom i.e. the same sonar properties

**Project 1: 0 files indexed**

The project structure looks like this:

```
D:.
│   .gitignore
│   Jenkinsfile
│   pom.xml
│   README.md
│
├───src
│   └───ch
│       └───swisscard
│           └───jenkins
│               └───pipeline
│                   └───util
│                           PipelineRabbitMQ.groovy
│
└───vars
        ciPipeline.groovy
```

So there are two groovy files which should be scanned but the logfile shows 0 files indexed:

```
[INFO] Base dir: D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\rabbitmq-ci-pipeline_master-2CYM2JXOI6CJM2T4MSNQTNPWY7LRY7PTSC3OG74TSX2Q2WNKXUSQ
[INFO] Working dir: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\rabbitmq-ci-pipeline_master-2CYM2JXOI6CJM2T4MSNQTNPWY7LRY7PTSC3OG74TSX2Q2WNKXUSQ\target\sonar
[INFO] Source paths: src, vars
[INFO] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] Included sources:
[INFO]   **/**
[INFO] Excluded sources:
[INFO]   **/target/**/*
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO] Included tests:
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO] 0 files indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

Project 2: Files properly scanned

The second project structure looks like this:

```
D:.
│   .gitignore
│   Jenkinsfile
│   pom.xml
├───src
│   └───main
│       │   Utils.groovy
└───vars
        checkQualityGate.groovy
        defaultBuildApplication.groovy
        ciPipeline.groovy
```

And here the log file indicates that all files were scanned:

```
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=98ms
[INFO] Base dir: D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\pipeline_feature_sonar-scan-D6GRAK5PLQOMGCOOH2T6QP6BP4LA6O3LP23UC7VBSSL3RORI4ZXQ
[INFO] Working dir: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\pipeline_feature_sonar-scan-D6GRAK5PLQOMGCOOH2T6QP6BP4LA6O3LP23UC7VBSSL3RORI4ZXQ\target\sonar
[INFO] Source paths: src, vars
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] Included sources:
[INFO]   **/**
[INFO] Excluded sources:
[INFO]   **/target/**/*
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO] Included tests:
[INFO]   **/*Test*/**
[INFO] 5 files indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

**Problem/Question**

So apparently both projects have the same configuration and similar structure, however one is scanned and another not. At the moment I don't understand why?
I have checked other topics which did not help me

- I do not have the `sonar.basedir` explicily set, but according to the log the base dir is fine

Comment: What changed in the last period? Have you upgraded some plugins? Plan to upgrade to the latest LTS version: 6.7.5.

Comment: So far nothing. I run both projects on the same Jenkins with same version sonar scanner and against same sonar server. Upgrade is planned but not in the next few weeks

Comment: Please execute commands in debug mode (`-X`) and add more logs (from the beginning of the scanner's execution).

Comment: I have the same issue, not sure to solve this.

Comment: same issue, any solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue for my project. I added `sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true` in the sonar properties and the files were indexed and scanned fine.